# How do I access my inactive GMail account?

Tags: gmail, google-account

A few years ago I created an GMail account, and over time it became inactive. Recently when trying to access it for reuse, it will not allow access with last known password.

When trying to reset the password it states that there is no account or email with that name.

When trying to recreate it as a new account it tells me that the email account or address is already in use and can not be used.

Using another email address I sent an email to that address and it was sent and was not returned undeliverable, so I would think it is still active, but will not allow the password to be reset.

Does anyone have any suggestions to help?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions at [Problems signing in to your account - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620?hl=en). If after that you still have problems to sign in to your account, post a question to the [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail).